# Font is not used when running as Windows Service

Tags: windows, fonts

On a Windows Server 2019 I have a program running as windows service which runs a normal user.
That program starts another exe programm written in c# which uses a crystal report to create a pdf file.
The report uses a font called 39251 to display a code39 barcode.

But the generated pdf does not contain the barcode but instead the representing numbers (e.g. *838348348*) It seems the report cannot find the font file or does not have access to it.

The service itself runs as the same windows user I use to login to windows.

But the weird thing is that when I run the program as user (not as service) then the exported pdf does contain the correct barcode.

I also changed the rights of the font file so everbody have full access to it.

Somebody an idea why the program cannot access the font when run as service but can access it when run manually.

Comment: have you worked this out? we have a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

right click on the font file and choose "Install for all users".
You'll be prompted for admin rights, click ok and this should solve your problem.

Comment: This solved the problem in my case. I still can't understand why as the installation was done by the same admin user that run the process...